# How to get second uitextfield calculated automatically after finishing typing in first uitextfield

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have 2 `uitextfields` (dollarPayTextField and rielPayTexField). After finishing typing in `dollarPayTextField`, I want `rielPayTextField` calculated automatically.

For example, total: 10 $, when I type in 9 $ in dollarPayTextField, I want rielPayTextField showing 4000. Thus, how I can do that ? This is my code for calculating the remain:

```
-(void)updateChangeRemainInriel{
    double dollarPay = [self.dollarPayTextField.text doubleValue];
    double dollarRemain = [self.abill getTotalPrice] - dollarPay;
    NSLog(@"%.2f",[self.dollarPayTextField.text doubleValue]);
    self.rielPayTextField.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",dollarRemain * self.anExchangeRate.rielBuyPerDollar];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you added **UITextFieldDelegate** in your .h file and **your_textField.delegate=self;** in your .m file. If you use this, it calculates every time the input is changed

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

   [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(yourTextFieldChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];  

    return YES;
}

- (void)yourTextFieldChanged:(UITextField *)textField
{
   double dollarPay = [self.dollarPayTextField.text doubleValue];
   double dollarRemain = [self.abill getTotalPrice] - dollarPay;
   NSLog(@"%.2f",[self.dollarPayTextField.text doubleValue]);
   self.rielPayTextField.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",dollarRemain *    self.anExchangeRate.rielBuyPerDollar];
}
```

if you use this, it calculates after you finish entering the value

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
   double dollarPay = [self.dollarPayTextField.text doubleValue];
   double dollarRemain = [self.abill getTotalPrice] - dollarPay;
   NSLog(@"%.2f",[self.dollarPayTextField.text doubleValue]);
   self.rielPayTextField.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",dollarRemain *    self.anExchangeRate.rielBuyPerDollar];
}
```

Comment: Yes! the second works, but the first doesn't ! So no way for automatic displaying !

Answer (score 0):

```
  - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
        {
               self.txtRiel.text=textField.text*100;// your calculation over here
        }
```

Also Refer Delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

refer the [Apple Documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html).